# Magento2 Multiple stores

Tags: magento-2.1, multistore, nginx

**I'm looking for clear solution without spikes, without creation any subfolders in pub with index files, without hardcoding cookies etc.**

In other words I'd like to achive multistore in magento only using nginx configuration and magento stores/configuration.

I mostly achieved this, however I'm using two stubs, which I want to remove.

I've created some stores in admin area. Then I configured for all of them base_url in stores/configuration (also in admin area).

Let's have a look at nginx configuration. I've put into it one stub:

I added

```
map $http_host $MAGE_RUN_CODE {
   sub1.domain.com "sub1_magento";
   sub2.domain.com "sub2_magento";
   sub3.domain.com "sub3_magento";
}
```

Then inside section for php files I've added this:

```
    fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE website;
    fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE $MAGE_RUN_CODE;
```

In `$_SERVER` variable `MAGE_RUN_TYPE` has expected value - 'website', however variable `$MAGE_RUN_CODE` doesn't have correct value.

For now I removed 'map' section and hardcoded value for it. 
*If somebody knows how to solve this nginx issue - please tell me how.*

**Let's move to the main issue:**

As I understand the main actions with store detection are happening inside

> Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver

If you put breakpoint inside constructor you may notice that `$runMode` and `$scopeCode` have expected values (from nginx config, as described above `MAGE_RUN_CODE` for me is hardcoded).

Then let's have a look at function:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getCurrentStoreId()
{
    list($stores, $defaultStoreId) = $this->getStoresData();

    $storeCode = $this->request->getParam(self::PARAM_NAME, $this->storeCookieManager->getStoreCodeFromCookie());

    if (is_array($storeCode)) {
        if (!isset($storeCode['_data']['code'])) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(__('Invalid store parameter.'));
        }
        $storeCode = $storeCode['_data']['code'];
    }
    if ($storeCode) {
        try {
            $store = $this->getRequestedStoreByCode($storeCode);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            $store = $this->getDefaultStoreById($defaultStoreId);
        }

        if (!in_array($store->getId(), $stores)) {
            $store = $this->getDefaultStoreById($defaultStoreId);
        }
    } else {
        $store = $this->getDefaultStoreById($defaultStoreId);
    }
    return $store->getId();
}
```

Store code is taking from one of two places: request or cookie.

In my opinion in case with request is when we type url like this: `http://sub1.domain.com/?__store=blablabla`. So it's not our case.

The second case (cookie) works only with store selector. (also not our case)

I **hardcoded** there necessary store name and I received expected result.

**Did I miss anything? Is there any third case? How should magento detect which store/website to use?**

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. I had some troubles with `MAGE_RUN_TYPE website;` because of detection default website in one function. I will not go deep inside the details, here is working solution:

The difference between current variant and posted in first post are `quotes`. They shouldn't present.

```
map $http_host $MAGE_RUN_CODE {
   sub1.domain.com sub1_magento;
   sub2.domain.com sub2_magento;
   sub3.domain.com sub3_magento;
}
```

Where sub1_magento, sub2_magento, sub3_magento are **store** codes!

Let's move below in the config:

```
# PHP entry point for main application
location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$ {

    ...

    fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
    fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE $MAGE_RUN_CODE;
```

Another issue, described in first post was 3rd party theme issue. So out of the box it must work!

Don't forget to have a look at official tutorials, they should help to solve all other issues:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-site/ms_over.html